# MySQL .Net Connector 8.0.26 not working with MySql server 5.7.23

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

I am not able use MySql .Net Connector version 8.0.26 to connect with MySql community server version 5.7.23 and getting below error :

> Exception : SSL Connection
> Inner Exception : An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
> NativeErrorCode : 10053

But same connector is working fine with MySql community server version 5.7.34.

In MySQL Connector 8.0.26 release note, it mentioned 5.7 as supported MySql server  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-26.html

Any suggestion.

Comment: Did you check version compatibilities?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes. I have updated the question with release note

Comment: looks like bug in Connector 8.0.26 to connect with MySql server 5.7.23. Upgraded the connector version to 8.0.27 and it is working fine now.